# Regex Capital letter combo

Tags: php, regex

REGEX is something of a mystery to me. After searching on SO, I did download Espresso and went through the tutorial, but things still are not clicking for me. It may just be my specific need, but I haven't found any examples. What I want to do is find matches that are exactly two  specific capital (or lowercase, mix) and then a string of numbers. Here are the cases I want to test against:

- `TL123`
- `TL 123`
- `tl123`
- `tl 123`
- `TLABC123`
- `tlabc123`

What I'm then trying to do is [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) the results for that match (and ultimately always return `TL-123` - for example).

So, any letter or number combo after `TL` would return `TL-` and vice-versa. Any nudges in the right direction would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

*Edit*

It might actually be [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) that I need for this.

Comment: I read the question twice and still don't understand what you're asking. Does capitalization matter or not? What are the "two specific capital"? Are you expecting `TL-123` to be returned for all the inputs above?

Comment: can there be something else than a space between the TL and those numbers? if so, what else or how many spaces min/max are you expecting?

Comment: Hi - sorry, capitalized or lowercased would return `TL-` if it found that two letter combination. To better explain it, if it finds `TL` anywhere, match it with `TL-`. Think it'll need preg_match_all, right?

Comment: I read it as case insensitive.  OP aware of `\i` [flags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php)?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter Anything after TL in theory would match. TL is used as a unique identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the specified pattern, you can use:

```
TL(?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)
```

This will match a `TL` followed by anything that isn't a number (or nothing) and then a list of numbers.

You could use this with PHP's `preg_replace()` like:

```
$str = preg_replace('/TL(?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)/i', 'TL-$1', $str);
```

This example, of course, assumes that `TL` is the exact characters you want to match. If `TL` is just a placeholder and you could match anything, you could use the following:

```
preg_replace('/([a-z]{2})(?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)/i', '$1-$2', $str);
```

With this, I have it hardcoded to only allow 2 characters to match (`{2}`). You can modify this to any number if you need it to change.

Also, as you want the matched characters to always be uppercase, but can *match* lowercase, I would suggest to just use `strtoupper()` around the result (instead of a callback).

Comment: So using the second example, if I was passing in that `TL` value as a variable, would it be: `preg_replace("/([a-z]{$VARIABLE})(?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)/i", '$1-$2', $str);`

Comment: The `{2}` specifies the number of times the pattern has to repeat, in this case, 2 times. If you want to make it dynamic, and `$VARIABLE='TL';`, you'll want to pass `strlen($VARIABLE)` to the regex. I would recommend hardcoding it if you know the length though.

Comment: Ah, actually I read that wrong, so `TL` is hardcoded in `preg_replace('/TL(?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)/i', 'TL-$1', $string);` what I'd like to do though is pass `TL` in as a variable, in both the search and the replace -- so not the count of characters, but the characters themselves

Comment: If you know the exact characters just use `"/{$VARIABLE}..."`, where `...` is the rest of the regex.

Comment: Awesome - http://pastebin.com/xrQsRKzj ended up working just fine. Thank you very much for the help!